# Unable to delete rows from .sdf database after deleting from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I have added a .sdf file(sqlceserver v3.5) to my winforms project.Then I added a .sdf database and select the dataset model for it. I also added a datagridview to this and selected its datasource as "LogBindingSource1" from the scroll pane. Rest code was generated automatically. I selected the columns of the datagridview.Now when i run the project and delete the rows from the grid, the changes are simply not reflecting into the database. 
I tried doing the following:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_UserDeletedRow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.UserDeletedRow  

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1
        'Me.Database1DataSet3.log.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert.ToUInt16(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Index).Cells(0).Value))
        'Me.LogTableAdapter1.Delete(Convert.ToUInt16(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Index).Cells(0).Value))
        'Me.DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Index)
        'Dim ind As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Index
        Me.LogBindingSource1.RemoveAt(e.Row.Index)
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        DataGridView1.Update()
        'Me.LogTableAdapter1.Update(Me.Database1DataSet3.Tables(0))
    Next

End Sub
```

I am showing the comments to show all the permutations which I tried. It must be noted that Log is the name of the table which has been bound to the grid and is the single table in database.

Before asking, I visited the following resources:
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575169/inserting-data-from-a-datagridview-to-a-sdf-sql-database
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575169/inserting-data-from-a-datagridview-to-a-sdf-sql-database (does not use table adapter)
3) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial (too verbose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed this unanswered question. Here is an easy way to go through your highlighted rows and delete from the `datagridview` and the database.   You will need to provide your own connection string and database name.  Here, I call it `Ranchconn`.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Ranchconn.Open()
    cmdRanch.Connection = Ranchconn
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In cdgvRanchEntry.SelectedRows
        cmdRanch.CommandText = "Delete * FROM Entries where ID = " & row.Cells("ID").Value
        cmdRanch.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cdgvRanchEntry.Rows.Remove(row)
    Next row
    Ranchconn.Close()
End Sub
```